# Missing link: Tracking email opens with google PHP mobile script

Tags: php, google-analytics, html-email

*Disclaimer: I know there are better ways to track email open rates, which are really a second-class metric anyway, but I need to solve this problem in this way for this issue, it's one-off problem.*

Question: **I need a quick and dirty way to track email opens.**  It's from our local mail server so no slick mail service features available. I've found a lot of articles and ideas that mostly revolve around the 1x1 gif. That's fine as the email I'm tracking is mostly images. I have researched a lot but have not found conclusive help - some of the methods are clearly open to SQL injection attacks, have resources with dead links, and others are just to vague for me to understand how to implement completely.

I've found the most promising solution from Google (gosh, I love those guys (and gals))

**Google offers a handy little PHP script for tracking page opens** on mobile sites here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/mobileWebsites

This PHP looks to be 90% of the problems solved. **I'm just a little fuzzy on how implement the workaround to embedd a tracking image/link into my outgoing email.**  Should I just embed the image link an use a mod rewrite to look for that image and then redirect to an http request to the google php script? Can I tag the image and have script run from that tag or.... It has to be from opening an email (and loading the images too) not clicking on a link.

Thank you in advance for your input. More detail is the better as I'm still learning.

All the Best!

--Chris M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic premise Chris is that you have a tracking image that isn't a normal `.jpg` or `.gif` image.

For example you would have an image like this inside your html email

```
<img src="trackerpage.php" width="1" height="1" />
```

Then on your tracking page you can grab some info from the user, perhaps by using a query string for a user id by adding this onto `trackerpage.php?id=1000`. Once you have have grabbed the detail you need to actually send an image back to the user.

To do this i suggest you have a read through this page : http://www.ehow.com/how_7280601_send-php-image-file.html

Leave a comment if you would like to expand on anything :)

Comment: Thanks for providing the link to help me fill out my understanding. "Teach a man to fish" is almost always my preferred route ;-)

Comment: If my answer helped would you please mark as answered by clicking the tick to the right of my answer?

Comment: Sure why not, I guess it's the best I'm going to get - thanks again.